# How to handle nested array response form API in angular

Tags: angular, http-post

How to handle following API response in Angular.

{ key: "some_value", testData: Array(3)}

Comment: Have you tried anything yet with some code to look at?

Comment: Please add more details to the question.

Comment: data.forEach((val, key) => {
          if( val !== undefined && val.key !== undefined) {
              keys.push(val.key);
              val.parDataModels.forEach(valData => {
              dataArray.push(valData.val1);
              units.push(valData.val1);
              values.push(valData.val1);
            })
          }
          
        })

Comment: Tried to extract object in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question -**

How to parse a response in an Angular application.

**Answer -**

Parsing a response can be done with JavaScript. You have an array within your example data so you need to loop through it. Each index other than the array can be accessed without a loop.

**Example -**

```
   const response = { key: "some_value", testData: [1, 2, 3,]};

// Returns the key which is not in the array
   console.log(response.key)

// returns the data in the array
    response.testData.forEach((c, i, a) => {
        // Do stuff with this current index
       console.log(c);
    });
```

**Additional Information -**

Keep in mind that your example data is a JavaScript Object. Typically an API repsonse will be JSON or XML. In your case, make sure you know if you are working with a JSON Oject or a JavaScript Object.

If the response is JSON, before using the code above convert the response.

Converting both directions.

JSON -> Object

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

Object -> JSON

```
JSON.stringify(response)
```